# F2 Visa work remote but without receive the payment in america

Tags: visa, working, payment

Let's say my wife gets a F1 Visa hence I get a F2 Visa and I work for another company outside of United States but I'll receive the payment to an account from my original country and I will use the credit/debit cards from my country in USA so as I'll never enter money in an American bank I guess I should be good, WDYT?

Comment: I think that is a very long sentence with no punctuation whatsoever…

Comment: Basically I asked if I can work with a F2 Visa if the money I earned goes to a foreign account.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether you can work in the US on an F2 visa without EAD - then no, you cannot.

If you're asking whether the location of the *employer* matters, or the location of the *bank* where your earnings are held matters - then no, they don't. Only your location is the one that matters.

If you're located in the US and your status is F2 - you cannot legally work.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I thought the reason of not allow work for a F2 was taxes, and basically if I earn money in a foreign account I don't need to pay taxes that's why  I thought maybe I could work with that kind of Visa.

Comment: @FrasesDeUrbanos it matters not at all for taxes which bank account you're using. The reason you're not allowed to work on F2 is because the US immigration law says so.

Comment: @FrasesDeUrbanos: You can't work while present in the US on F2. But if you work (illegally) anyway, you will be subject to US taxes on your income. Where the employer is located and where the bank account is don't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I've received my F2 already and I told my employer about this so I quit my job in good terms, as my wife magister will only takes a year they will hire me again when I come back.

Comment: Again thank you so much